# MV C++ 14.0 or greater is required

Tags: python

I am trying to install Bloomberg API using  `python -m pip install --index-url=https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple blpapi` as per their website. But I get an error

```
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
          [end of output]
```

Which is strange because I do have Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 2022 installed. i even added the env variable: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\Hostx64\x64.

Does anyone knows a solution, Bloomberg helpdesk is recommending to read their documentation which obviously does NOT provide a coverage of the problem.

Comment: if you have msvc installed properly, start menu should have something like "Developer Command Prompt" .. Open that and try pip install again,

Comment: Install python 3.9+

Comment: Confirmed @DJB, it worked! thank you !

Comment: Very good. You can now install xbbg and you should be able to pull data from Bloomberg.

Comment: Confirmed, I could install XBBG and it works well!